# When run poetry install, console shows "no pyproject.toml or setup.py"

Tags: python, python-poetry

## Environment

- Mac OS v13.1
- Python3 v3.10.8
- pyenv v2.3.14
- Poetry v1.4.0

## What want to do

I'd like to challenge [this repo](https://github.com/0xPARC/plonkathon).

## What happened

When I run '$poetry install', below error displayed.

```
Installing dependencies from lock file

Package operations: 0 installs, 1 update, 0 removals

  • Updating merlin (0.1.0 /Users/hoge/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/plonkathon-OEAbpZSY-py3.10/src/curdleproofs.pie/merlin -> 0.1.0 805d067): Failed

  BuildException

  Source /Users/hoge/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/plonkathon-OEAbpZSY-py3.10/src/curdleproofs.pie does not appear to be a Python project: no pyproject.toml or setup.py

  at ~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/site-packages/build/__init__.py:135 in _validate_source_directory
      131│         raise BuildException(f'Source {srcdir} is not a directory')
      132│     pyproject_toml = os.path.join(srcdir, 'pyproject.toml')
      133│     setup_py = os.path.join(srcdir, 'setup.py')
      134│     if not os.path.exists(pyproject_toml) and not os.path.exists(setup_py):
    → 135│         raise BuildException(f'Source {srcdir} does not appear to be a Python project: no pyproject.toml or setup.py')
      136│ 
      137│ 
      138│ def check_dependency(
      139│     req_string: str, ancestral_req_strings: tuple[str, ...] = (), parent_extras: Set[str] = frozenset()
```

Is there a problem with merlin? Or is there a problem with my development environment?

All feedback is welcome.

I tried removing `/Users/hoge/Library/Caches/pypoetry/`, the result is not changed.

Also, I runned `poetry env remove && poetry install`, result is same.

## PS

I noticed that the directory specified in plonkathon/pyproject.toml is not referenced. Why is this?

```
merlin = {git = "https://github.com/nalinbhardwaj/curdleproofs.pie", rev = "master", subdirectory = "merlin"}
```

Comment: Does the mentioned directory contain the file Poetry is looking for or not? What is in `/Users/hoge/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/plonkathon-OEAbpZSY-py3.10/src/curdleproofs.pie` directory?

Comment: Maybe this is a known issue: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/7575 -- Which version of Poetry are you using?

Comment: I using Poetry v1.4.0, and I confirmed there are same components as https://github.com/nalinbhardwaj/curdleproofs.pie

Comment: Maybe it is fixed in Poetry 1.4.1 that was just released: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/releases/tag/1.4.1

Comment: oh, Yes! I solved it after updating v1.4.1, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This was a [known bug](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/7575) in Poetry. It is now [solved](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/pull/7580) in its [version *1.4.1*](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/releases/tag/1.4.1).